# What does it mean for a cache to be 2 way? 4 way? What characteristics does it change when compared to a direct mapped cache?

Tags: caching

*I am new to machine assembly and would like to have some insight as to the difference between a cache being 2-way and 4-way.*

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/set-associative-cache This article is a great resource to learn about it and maybe this question belongs to TCS stack-exchange.